# Using ещё and пока

Tags: значения, синонимы

When to use `ещё` and when to use `пока`?

`С утра пока темно.`

`С утра ещё темно.`

Is there any difference in the meaning in these  examples?

EDIT:

As @Alex.S said, there is also one other variant:

`С утра пока ещё темно`. So, what are the differences in the meaning if they exist?

Comment: The first sounds weird. To confuse you a bit more: "С утра пока ещё темно" is totally okay.

Comment: `С утра пока темно` It sounds more like "In the morning, while it was still dark, [someone started to do smth.]". I guess native speakers could say this from time to time, but in fact it's a speech mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first sounds like an unfinished sentence, like a clause because пока in your sentence means **while**.In the morning while it's dark or while it's still dark...(С утра пока темно...or С утра, пока еще темно,я готовлю завтрак).

The second is OK.In the morning it's still dark. It sounds like a background for a story.
Пока and еще have got several meanings. The main are:
1.at the moment, now, waiting for some time.

> Я пока подожду.
>   Пока мне ста рублей достаточно.

2 пока еще or пока--still, yet

> Пока еще ждем.(we are still waiting).Пока еще не уехали.(we haven't left yet.)

3.пока--while

> Куй железо, пока горячо.(Make hay while the sun shines)

4пока--until

> Сиди здесь, пока не приду.(Stay here till I come).

ЕЩЁ, 
1. (ещё). --again

> Ещё раз.

2. (ещё) --in addition с предшествующими союзами, и, да.

   > Дайте мне масла, муки и ещё сахару. Он способный, образованный, да ещё добрый.
   >   | Он мало способен, да еще ленив.
3. (еще). already

   > Дом сгорел еще в прошлом году.

4.еще--still

> . Молод ты еще, чтоб курить.

5еще--having enough time

> . Я еще успею на поезд.

6. (ещё) --more при прил. и нареч. сравн.

   > Она стала ещё красивее.

Answer (score 2):

> С утра пока темно. = Not a phrase. As has been mentioned, it looks
>   like "In the morning, while it is still dark...", requiring a continuation. And a comma before пока.
>
> С утра ещё темно. = In the morning it is still dark. Means, well, it is still too dark in the morning for the proposed activity.
>
> С утра пока ещё темно. = It is still dark in the morning in this part of the year/season. Means you need to wait some months for it being not that dark in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, "пока" is closer to "yet", whereas "ещё" is closer to "still". "Пока" implies continuation: `С утра пока темно[, но скоро будет светлее].` You can even combine these words, to make the opposition even stronger: `...пока ещё темно, [но совсем скоро уже будет светло]`.